# MySql Select Result Having Combined Multiple Queries From Both the Same Table and Others

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table ('names') which includes data related with other data in other tables relying on ids. For example:

*Names table

```
id |     name     | predecessor | successor | house | birthplace 
-----------------------------------------------------------------
10    Bayezid II         9           11         4         NULL
11    Selim I            10          12         4         5
12    Suleiman           11          13         4         61
```

*Houses table

```
id |  house
--------------
4    House of Osman
```

*Places table

```
id |  place
--------------
5    Amasya
61   Trabzon
```

What I'm trying to accomplish is to construct a query which results in returning whole information depending on the id, like:

```
{"result":[{
    "id":"11",
    "name":"Selim I",
    "predecessor": "Bayezid II",
    "successor": "Suleiman",
    "house":"House of Osman",
    "birthplace":"Amasya"
}]}
```

So, the name of the house and the birthplace are brought from other tables ('houses', 'places') whereas the predecessor and the successor are from the same table. I need help constructing this query. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just self-join a couple times, once to get the predecessor's row (aliased `n0` below), and once more for the successor's (`n2`):

```
SELECT n1.id, n1.name, n0.name AS predecessor, n2.name AS successor
FROM names n1
LEFT JOIN names n0 ON n1.predecessor = n0.id
LEFT JOIN names n2 ON n1.successor = n2.id
```

[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fdc53/1)

Joining to get the house and birthplace are left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: Thank you for your quick help. However, what i need is not whole information but whole information "depending on id". Whole info about only one requested name should be returned.

Comment: This is done with a simple `WHERE` clause. Add `WHERE n1.id = 11` at the end of the statement.

Comment: @nonkertompf No offense, but you should go out and learn some simple SQL then. I assumed your question was on the self join (the hard part). The rest, including what you want from that comment, can be accomplished very simply, and SO is not really intended to just do other people's work.

Comment: @lc No, I'm not offended. On the contrary, grateful but I'm afraid I couldn't have managed to properly ask what I'm after. I know about the WHERE clause :) I want to understand what makes your query different than Rahul's because it returns directly the same results as yours and also including the house and birthplace WITHOUT any where clause. On the other hand, without the house and the birthplaces returned from other tables, it is of no use to me. Thanks again for your kindness and sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: The only things I can see different between the two queries is he is also selecting the house and birthplace columns (but as raw IDs, not getting the name, so it doesn't really "help" in the true sense of the word) and he does actually have a WHERE clause. If you look at the SQL Fiddle demo I linked to, you can see the result set shows all rows, which you can of course add a WHERE clause to. You can play with the query a bit there too. Other than this I'm not sure what else is different?

Comment: @nonkertompf A great difference between both answers is the use of `LEFT JOIN` by lc. and `INNER JOIN` by Rahul. If there aren't matching rows with those `id` values in your table, this answer will give you `NULL` values in those fields. Rahuls answer will give you no row at all.

Comment: @nonkertompf You get `house` and `birthplace` the same way by joining those tables according to their ids. With current data you can't get a birthplace for Bayezid II, so you better use left joins too.

Comment: @lc Yes, you're right. I never meant that his query is of any better help than yours. And he added that where clause later. And with or without that added, the same result is returned. Isn't it weird or mea culpa? Just try his query with and without the where clause and notice the difference between his and yours. That query returns data of Selim I, including the house and the birthplace (raw), yours returns all three without the house and the birthplace if no where clause is included in the query. I don't understand.

Comment: @VMai Thank you very much. Now I see the difference between the two queries after your clear and considerate explanations. Thank you very much all of you.

Comment: Sorry I didn't notice the inner join at first. That's exactly why (even before the WHERE). ...As you also see now too.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select n.id,
n.name,
n1.name as predecessor,
n2.name as successor,
h.house,
p.place
from names n
inner join names n1 on n.id = n1.predecessor
inner join names n2 on n.id = n2.successor
left join Houses h on n.house = h.id
left join Place p on n.birthplace = p.id
where n.id = 11
```

Comment: Thank you. Strange enough for me that it returns the same result with or without the where clause you added after. And I also need the results of the house and birthplace returned from their own tables. That's the hard part I need help about, actually.

Comment: @nonkertompf, that's not hard at all. what you need to do is post the actual table columns for tables holding house and birthplace column likewise you have posted names table.

Comment: @nonkertompf, check edited answer. Use that updated query; it will get you house and birth place information as well.

Comment: thank you, you're very helpful. have you checked lc's answer? i guess left joining is better than inner as Vmai said. Wouldn't you rather use left instead of inner joins?

Comment: @nonkertompf, per your posted table I saw that all the matching ID are present and so went for inner join. Only difference b/w inner and left join is that; in case no matching ID inner will not return the row at all whereas left join will return the row with NULL values for joined table. Yes, LEFT join would be a better idea in case you are not sure that matching ID's are present. See in my query, for joining with house and place table I have used LEFT JOIN.

Comment: @nonkertompf, no offense but don't forget to accept any one of the answer which you have found useful. Thanks.

Comment: no, i haven't. i was just checking out your code again and it seems the successor and the predecessor are swapped ;)